# I want to display two items in one row in listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I wanted to show 2 items on a single row in textfield,How can I place 2 items in the same row in listview?

I want something like this to be displayed :

```
item 1 

item 2|item3

item 4

item 5 | item 6
```

My code :

```
public class MultipleItemsList extends ListActivity {

    private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
        int count=0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {

            if(count==0){
                mAdapter.addItem("item " + i);
                count++;
            }
            else if (count == 1) {
                mAdapter.addSeparatorItem("item " + i);
                count++;
            }
            else  if(count==2){
                mAdapter.addSeparatorItem1("item "+i);
                count=0;
            }
        }
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
        private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR1=2;
        private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

        private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorSet1=new TreeSet<Integer>();
        public MyCustomAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public void addItem(final String item) {
            mData.add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
            mData.add(item);
            // save separator position
            mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        public void addSeparatorItem1(final String item){
            mData.add(item);
            mSeparatorSet1.add(mData.size()-1);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if(mSeparatorsSet.contains(position)){
                return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
            }
            else if(mSeparatorSet1.contains(position)){
                return TYPE_SEPARATOR1;
            }
            else
                return TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch (type) {
                    case TYPE_ITEM:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                        break;
                    case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                        break;
                    case TYPE_SEPARATOR1:
                        convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2,null);
                        holder.textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator1);
                        break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }
}
```

Comment: ListView can only show one Item in a row. However if you have 2 sub-items within one Item then you can do that. Like adding two TextViews in each rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView doesn't really support this kind of operation. Items in a ListView must be stacked vertically. And the inner implementation of ListView will prevent any simple attempt to convince it to lay items out differently.

Check out the GridLayout control in the compatibility library. That covers what you want to do fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying two items in one row, you must use LinearLayout as parent with weight 1. Orientation of linear layout must be horizontal.
add two childs with weight 0.5 inside the linear layout.
Definitely not the only way to  do it but it will do what you ask for.
Hope it helps.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textSeparator"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:text="text"
  android:visibility="visible"
  android:layout_width="194dp"
  android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
  android:background="#FFFF0000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSeparator1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="194dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:background="#FFFF0000" />

Comment: sorry i am new to stackoverflow i don't know how to write readable code in comment

Comment: Should be layout_weight, not weight, and that's not actually how layout_weight works. The weight of the parent has no effect on how children are laid out, so a weight should not be given to the LInearLayout. . Excess space is divided among the children with weight in proportion to the weights assigned. You could set the weights of the two children to 1 (rather than 0.5). Also doens't really address the OP's question.

Comment: This is what it looks when i run 

                   ITEM 1
new Row  :ITEM 2      text
new Row :text           ITEM 3
       new Row :ITEM 4
new Row :  ITEM 5      text
new Row   text          ITEM 6

Comment: check out the gridview in android